# DataGridView + DataTable, best way of handling huge lists?

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I have a DataTable which will contain about couple thousand rows, each row has about 20 fields.

In addition, the values in cells will change live. Also some rows will get deleted and some added while running.

**The first problem** I'm facing is that when I have the app open and call DataGrid.DataSource = .. The DataGrid doesn't show data at first, I have to minimize the app and then bring it back on for data to show up, why is this happening?

**The second problem** is that each row will be updated from a separate thread. I kept getting 'Index Corrupted' Exception and then I found out I can't update dataTable from seperate threads, therefor I created a class with all the cells, created List and made threads update the class data directly and then another single thread updates the dataTable, that seemed to work fine, but is there a better way of doing this?

Basically I need a DataGrid, that supports couple thousand rows which are going to be updated/removed/added live (by threads, not user). What is the best way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the data table would be my first thought, the only time you really need it if you want to apply all these changes done by threads ( or anyone else for that matter) to the backend.

This list class you've knocked up. If you get it to Implement IList, you can bind to it like it is a DataTable

Once you are in control as in using your class and not DataTable, you can have look at the when and how of BindingNotifications.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem of the UI not updating could (possibly) be solve by updating the `DataGridView` using `myDataGridView.Update()`, this will refresh/update this control only and is more efficient than refreshing the entire form (I am assuming that you are using WinForms).

The solution to second problem depends on what sort of threading you are adopting (which you don't state). Assuming that you are using TPL, the insertion of data into the `DataGridView` can be done using a [`TaskSheduler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.THREADING.TASKS.TASKSCHEDULER%29%3bk%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22%29%3bk%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) so from within the method that you are running on a separate thread you would have

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        source1.DataSource = dtAll;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = source1;
    }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, _uiScheduler);
```

where the `TaskScheduler` is defined from the UI thread via

```
TaskScheduler _uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
```

and passed into you asynchronous method. I hope this helps.